# Microservices and Ionic

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, rabbitmq, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

Can you build a mobile app using ionic from a MEAN stack that utilizes micro services with AMQPS communication? My primary concern is if I'm building out micro services with Bluemix and each instance is independent - how would I migrate this architecture to a mobile app.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few considerations when integrating [Bluemix Mobile services](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/starters/mobilefirst-services-starter/) into your current MEAN-AMPQS architecture:

**Keep your Mobile Back-End completely separate**

Since [IBM Push Notifications](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/ibm-push-notifications/) (and associated [Node.js](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/starters/sdk-for-nodejs/) runtime) can be accessed via REST, your mobile back-end app can be hosted on Bluemix, away from your existing work. You focus on creating your Mobile app to talk directly to what you already have.

Your interaction with Bluemix will be through the Bluemix Push Notifications dashboard, to configure native services and send notifications, and the [Mobile Clent Access](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/mobile-client-access/) dashboard to configure mobile authentication. Once you have the SDK incorporated into your app  You can also automate push messages through the REST api and require Facebook, Google+, or custom auth.

See [IBM Push Notifications REST API](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobilepush/c_push_notification.html) and [MCA documentation](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/mobileaccess/index.html) for details.

**Migrate Your Entire MEAN Stack to Bluemix**

The entirety of your MEAN stack is available on [Bluemix](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/) and so are some MQ messaging services. This might not be exacty the same, but Bluemix provides the capability to do what you want completely in the cloud. You will also be saving space since the mobile services are bound to a Node.js runtime by default.

This may **not** be a good decision if you have sensitive data that you need secured on-site.

**Keep Mongo DB Local and your Express Angular Node App on Bluemix**

A good way to save time and space if you need your Mongo DB local. All your node code will be good to go on the Bluemix hosted runtime.